# How to delete a record in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cql3

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    user_id int,
    device_id ascii,
    record_time timestamp,
    timestamp timeuuid,
    info_1 text,
    info_2 int, 
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, device_id, record_time, timestamp)
);
```

When I ask Cassandra to delete a record (an entry in the columnfamily) like this:

```
DELETE from my_table where user_id = X and device_id = Y and record_time = Z and timestamp = XX;
```

it returns without an error, but when I query again the record is still there. Now if I try to delete a whole row like this:

```
DELETE from my_table where user_id = X
```

It works and removes the whole row, and querying again immediately doesn't return any more data from that row.

What I am doing wrong? How you can remove a record in Cassandra?

Thanks

Comment: What is the type of your `timestamp` column?  Timestamp or timeuuid?  Also, can you edit your post with the statement you are using to insert your data?

Comment: `record_time` is `timestamp` while `timestamp` is `timeuuid`. When I use the same statement to update the entry, it works just fine. For delete, it returns without error, but the entry is still there and I can query it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, here is my theory as to what is going on.  You have to be careful with timestamps, because they will *store* data down to the millisecond.  But, they will only *display* data to the second.  Take this sample table for example:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT id, datetime  FROM data;

 id     | datetime
--------+--------------------------
 B25881 | 2015-02-16 12:00:03-0600
 B26354 | 2015-02-16 12:00:03-0600

(2 rows)
```

The `datetime`s (of type timestamp) are equal, right?  Nope:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT id, blobAsBigint(timestampAsBlob(datetime)),
                                  datetime FROM data;

 id     | blobAsBigint(timestampAsBlob(datetime)) | datetime
--------+-----------------------------------------+--------------------------
 B25881 |                           1424109603000 | 2015-02-16 12:00:03-0600
 B26354 |                           1424109603234 | 2015-02-16 12:00:03-0600

(2 rows)
```

As you are finding out, this becomes problematic when you use timestamps as part of your PRIMARY KEY.  It is possible that your timestamp is storing more precision than it is showing you.  And thus, you will need to provide that hidden precision if you will be successful in deleting that single row.

Anyway, you have a couple of options here.  One, find a way to ensure that you are not entering more precision than necessary into your `record_time`.  Or, you could define `record_time` as a timeuuid.

Again, it's a theory.  I could be totally wrong, but I have seen people do this a few times.  Usually it happens when they insert timestamp data using `dateof(now())` like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (key, time, data) VALUES (1,dateof(now()),'blah blah');
```

Comment: Nice catch. That was the issue. I had this issue long ago and totally forgot about this limitation of CQL. And the JIRA for it still is Won't Fix (I don't understand why!). Thankfully I am dealing with data through my app so don't have the problem there, but while I was checking it in CQL got me quite confused. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE worker_login_table (
    worker_id text,
    logged_in_time timestamp, 
    PRIMARY KEY (worker_id, logged_in_time)
);

INSERT INTO worker_login_table (worker_id, logged_in_time) 
   VALUES ("worker_1",toTimestamp(now()));
```

after 1 hour executed the above insert statement once again

```
select * from worker_login_table;

 worker_id| logged_in_time
----------+--------------------------
 worker_1 | 2019-10-23 12:00:03+0000
 worker_1 | 2015-10-23 13:00:03+0000

(2 rows)
```

Query the table to get absolute timestamp

```
select worker_id, blobAsBigint(timestampAsBlob(logged_in_time )), logged_in_time from worker_login_table;

worker_id     | blobAsBigint(timestampAsBlob(logged_in_time)) | logged_in_time 
--------+-----------------------------------------+--------------------------
 worker_1 |                           1524109603000 | 2019-10-23 12:00:03+0000
 worker_1 |                           1524209403234 | 2019-10-23 13:00:03+0000

(2 rows)
```

The below command **will not delete** the entry from Cassandra as the precise value of timestamp is required to delete the entry

```
DELETE from worker_login_table where worker_id='worker_1' and logged_in_time ='2019-10-23 12:00:03+0000';
```

By using the timestamp from blob **we can delete** the entry from Cassandra

```
DELETE from worker_login_table where worker_id='worker_1' and logged_in_time ='1524209403234';
```